# FFmpeg and mencoder

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mencoder

Currently i am making 2 videos with this command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 25 -t 5 -i /home/psafari/public_html/youtube_images/movie_" . $id . ".jpg -q:v 1 -an /home/psafari/public_html/youtube_videos/".$movie1."

ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 25 -t ".$t." -i /home/psafari/public_html/yy.jpg -q:v 1 -an /home/psafari/public_html/youtube_videos/".$movie2."
```

And it also works, but when i will make 2 videos into 1, it only shows 5 seconds of the first video (like the other doesn't comvert also).

```
mencoder -ovc copy -o /home/psafari/public_html/final_".time().".avi /home/psafari/public_html/youtube_videos/".$movie1." /home/psafari/public_html/youtube_videos/".$movie2
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: what type of files are movie1 and movie2?

Comment: movie1 and movie2 should have the same parameters (video codec, resolution, frame rate, ...)